# octobercms can't connect to DB; .env is fine and php artisan tinker / echo env('DB_*') outputs correct content

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I'm using OctoberCMS and, using the DB settings in the .env file I can connect to the DB without issue and I see a database named "mydatabase". BUT when I do `php artisan tinker` and do `DB::connection()->getPdo();` I get the following:

```
InvalidArgumentException with message 'Database (mydatabase) does not exist.'
```

When I do `echo env('DB_HOST');` and `echo env('DB_PORT');` etc (for DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD) everything looks good. I can connect with those parameters with the mysql CLI command. And yet `DB::connection()->getPdo();` is failing.

Any ideas?

I'm running OctoberCMS 1.0.443. `tail -f /path/to/myproject/storage/logs/system.log` doesn't return anything (despite being writable)

Comment: The error is saying that the database called `mydatabase` doesnt exist. It's not saying the connection settings are wrong so `DB_HOST` and `DB_PORT` are not where the problem is. If you run a `CREATE SCHEMA mydatabase;` would it work?

Comment: @apokryfos - the DB exists. `SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) FROM Information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mydatabase';` says there are ~1,300 rows. My company has a working OctoberCMS install on a prod server - I'm trying to connect to a local install of OctoberCMS that connects to the prod DB. I can connect to it fine using the mysql CLI client (as the SQL query I just provided demonstrates) - I just can't seem to connect using `DB::connection()->getPdo()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have DB_DATABASE set in my .env. I had all the other DB_* values but not that one...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using the .env file correctly? If you don't have calls to `env()` in your `config/database.php` file, then it won't be used. October does not use a `.env` file by default, you would either have had to add those calls yourself to the configuration files or you would have had to run `php artisan october:env` to do it automatically for you.